# Problems with running PostgresSQL together with node/express in Docker. FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker, express, docker-compose

I'm trying to get a development enviroment running in Docker.

I have a `docker-compose` file with 4 services: frontend, postgres, pgadmin4 and node/express. If I run postgres in Docker and Express locally, I can connect to the database. If I try to run Express and Postgres in Docker, Express is working and I can also connect to postgres via `pgadmin4`, but i get:

```
FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
```

when i try my endpoint that connects to the database.

After searching in Google I think this has something to do with environment variables not being set properly for some reason. Also I am a little confused as to how hostnames work and what hostname to use where? Hostname of my machine? Localhost? Name of docker service? Anyways, here are my configs:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend/
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/usr/app/
      - ./frontend/node_modules
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
 
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=exampledb
 
  db_admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - '5555:80'
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=asdf
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=asdf
    depends_on:
      - db
 
  api:
    build: ./backend/api/
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./backend/api/:/usr/app/
      - /backend/api/node_modules
    ports:
      - '3333:3333'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**JS code to connect to postgres**

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const client = new Pool({
    host: 'db',
    port: '5432',
    username: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'exampledb'
  })

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => client.query(text, params),
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The frontend service may be running before the database has initialized. Try to wait for the database to be ready using dockerize in your Dockerfile. See: https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize#waiting-for-other-dependencies

Comment: @DonnyVerduijn i don't think this is it. The frontend isn't involved at the moment, im just testing the db through and express endpoint in the browser. Doesn't matter if i wait an hour for it to start up.

Comment: Sorry, i meant your api service. Your api service will not wait for your db service to be ready. Using depends_on or links in your docker-compose file will only enforce the startup order of your services, but the services will not wait before the actual applications inside are ready.

Comment: I don't think you should use `=` while setting environment variables.  You should be using `:` instead.  Take a look at some examples [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).

Comment: @abhishek_naik tried setting version to 3.1 and using the same syntax as in those examples. Still getting the same error. db_1        | 2019-11-18 18:40:43.269 UTC [68] FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name s
pecified in startup packet                                                      
api_1       | error: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet

Comment: Got it working with mariadb instead, gonna have to try postgres another time. Thanks to everyone for trying to help!

Comment: "*Express is working and I can also connect to postgres via pgadmin4*" - if it is working, then where exactly are you getting this error message?

Comment: @abhishek_naik That is not correct. Both dictionary notation `KEY:VALUE` and list notation `- KEY=VALUE` are allowed in [docker-compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

Answer (score 1):

On your Pool Connection, it should read like this:

```
const client = new Pool({
    host: 'db',
    port: '5432',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'exampledb'
})

module.exports = {
    query: (text, params) => client.query(text, params),
}
```

Change `username` to `user` for your key and you should be golden.